# How can I prevent Docker Compose volumes from overwriting changes by `composer install`?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a Docker container.

I have volume in my docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
  - "./:/var/www/html"
```

In my Dockerfile I run composer install

RUN composer install --no-progress --no-interaction

but vendor directory is not created (either in container, either on host machine)

Comment: Post your Dockerfile also

Answer (score 0):

Volumes are mounted after the Dockerfile is ran. Your volume mount is overwritting anything that would have been in that directory already. You will need to run composer inside the container after standing it up with that compose file.